# Can I use symlink to a Python virtual environment in my shebang statement?

Tags: python, linux, python-venv

I have set up a python virtual environment on a new linux server. I have a number of existing scripts I'd like to avoid changing (for various reasons) - these all have a shebang which points to a python installation not on the new server.

My hope was that I could create the same directory structure on the new server as well as a symlink on the new server that points to the new venv. If I specify the venv python installation in the shebang, my script runs correctly, recognizing the packages I installed, however if I run it with the symlink in the shebang, the script does not use the venv and fails.

This script uses a symlink I created using `ln -s: /opt/{path on old server}/python -> /opt/test/test_venv368/bin/python3`

**Failing Script:**

```
#!/opt/{path on old server}/python
import sys
print(sys.executable)
import pyodbc
modulenames = set(sys.modules) & set(globals())
allmodules = [sys.modules[name] for name in modulenames]
print(allmodules)
```

Outputs:

```
/opt/{path on old server}/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testvenv3.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pyodbc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'
```

**Successful when not using a symlink:**

```
#!/opt/{venv path}/python
import sys
print(sys.executable)
import pyodbc
modulenames = set(sys.modules) & set(globals())
allmodules = [sys.modules[name] for name in modulenames]
print(allmodules)
```

Outputs:

```
/opt/test/test_venv368/bin/python
[<module 'sys' (built-in)>, <module 'pyodbc' from '/opt/test/test_venv368/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>]
```

I have checked the permissions on and recreated the symlink. The sticking point to me is that the script runs correctly with the venv as the shebang and not when the symlink is used.

I'm also open if there is a way to force use of a specific python installation via the user profile. (As long as the script can remain untouched.) Having the user profile start with an activated venv doesn't work when running the script as an executable (which it needs to be).

Comment: The shebang doesn't change the environment where the script runs. It's roughly equivalent to running the command `/opt/{path on old server}/python scriptname.py` in your regular shell.

Comment: you created a symbolic link with `ln -l` ?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, that is my understanding too. When I instead specify the interpreter when I call the script `/opt/{path on old server}/python scriptname.py` I receive the import errors above however `/opt/test/test_venv368/bin/python scriptname.py` is successful. I was thinking there is some reason the I can't set a venv python installation as a symlink? That's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: The script should probably not have a shebang at all, unless it is actually *installed* (via pip, for example), in which case a shebang like `#!python` will be automatically changed to the version of Python that executed `pip`. Otherwise, simply run the script explicitly with whatever Python you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was happening:

Both scripts were using the same installation of Python (in the venv), however launching the first/failing executable script even within an activated venv did not correctly locate the modules in the venv's site-packages folder.

To fix this, we set the PYTHONPATH environment variable by adding `export PYTHONPATH=/opt/test/test_venv368/lib/python3.6/site-packages/` to the user profile.

Printing `sys.path` inside each run of the script showed differences in where it was looking for modules.